# tf.contrib.lookup.HashTable issue

Tags: tensorflow, lookup-tables

I try to upgrade a cost function in which I need to calculate a lookup table:

```
tf_look_up_keys = tf.as_string(tf.range(0, int(N+1), dtype=tf.int32 ))
tf_look_up_values = ....an array of N+1 elements ....
tf.contrib.lookup.HashTable(tf.contrib.lookup.KeyValueTensorInitializer(tf_look_up_keys, tf_look_up_values), -1)
```

but when I start the session it tells this:

tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Table not initialized.

```
>          [[Node: hash_table_Lookup = LookupTableFind[Tin=DT_STRING, Tout=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@hash_table"],
> _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](hash_table, AsString_1, hash_table/Const)]]
```

what should I do? In which way I can initialize (I tried to move up tf.global_variables_initializer() but it results in a long list of complains about other variables that before this modification were ok)
Thank you, 
cheers

Comment: does ``table = tf.contrib.lookup.HashTable(tf.contrib.lookup.KeyValueTensorInitializer(tf_look_up_keys, tf_look_up_values), -1) `` work when you call ``table.init.run()`` after it?

Comment: the process stops at the line in which I define table.

Comment: It seems there is a problem in a different piece of code. I was able to ran your code with an array of N+1 float elements in a session and got no error message.

Answer (score 6):

You need to inialize tables by `tf.tables_initializer`.
Alternatively you can use MonitoredSession which does initialization for you.

Comment: Using `session.run(tf.tables_initializer())` solved the problem for me, while executing `index_to_label_table.init.run()` didn't work sometimes.